# SSH to aks Windows node: azureuser@(windows node internal ip address)'s password

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssh, azure-aks

I'm trying to SSH into AKS windows node using this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) which created debugging Linux node, and ssh into the windows node from the debugging node. Once I enter the Linux node and try to SSH into the windows node, it asks me to type in azureuser password like below:

```
azureuser@10.240.0.128's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What is `azureuser@(windows node internal IP address)'s` password? Is it my azure service password or is it a `WindowsProfileAdminUserPassword` that I pass in when I create an AKS cluster using `New-AzAksCluster` `cmdlet`? Or is it my ssh keypair password? If I do not know what it is, is there a way I can reset it? Or is there a way I can create a Windows node free from credentials? Any help is appreciated. Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to login with your password, not your ssh key. Look for the [explanation](https://www.thorntech.com/passwords-vs-ssh/) between those methods. These are two different authentication methods. If you want to ssh to your node, you need to chose ssh with key authentication. You can do this by running the command:

```
ssh -i <id_rsa> azureuser@<your.ip.adress>
```

But before this, you need to create key pair. It is well done described in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh#before-you-begin). Then you can [create the SSH connection to a Linux node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh#create-the-ssh-connection-to-a-linux-node). You have everything described in detail, step by step, in the documentation you provide.

When you configure everything correctly, you will be able to log into the node using the ssh key pair. You won't need a password. When you execute the command

```
ssh -i <id_rsa> azureuser@<your.ip.adress>
```

you should see an output like this:

```
The authenticity of host '10.240.0.67 (10.240.0.67)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFG.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

[...]

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1935]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

When you see `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` you need to write `yes` and confirm using `Enter`.